# Algorithm Design- Identify single bottle in wine cellar with fewest testers

Tags: algorithm

This is for extra credit in an algorithms class.  The problem states

> A king has a wine cellar of N bottles, and a single bottle has been poisoned.
>       The poison takes approximately a month to work.  The king wants the exact bottle
>       identified using the fewest testers possible within a months time.

My solution is

- Split up the `N` bottles into `M` lots and use ``M testers

  - The first tester tastes both the first and last lot
  - The second tester tastes both the first and second lots.
  - The third tester tastes both the second and third lots.
  - Continue on for M lots, with testers overlapping lots.
- When the two testers that tasted the tainted wine become ill, the lot has been identified.  The `M-2` testers left each taste one bottle from the tainted lot, and the third tester that becomes ill identifies the tainted bottle.

However, this algorithm requires double the time allotted to work: one month to identify the tainted lot, and a second month to identify the tainted bottle.  Is there a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: "Within a month's time"... Your proposal has a second tasting, but as I read the problem it could be restated to explicitly say there is only a single tasting.

Comment: There is a (relatively) easy way to do this with 2*SQRT(N) testers within a single month, which is probably the answer looked for.  There is a somewhat more sophisticated way to do it with Log2(N) testers, which will always be less.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can do it with `log2(N)` testers with a pretty neat algorithm.

Let me demonstrate it with a simple example. Assume `N = 1000`.

If we label the bottles `0` through `999`, then each bottle can be represented by a unique binary number ranging from `0000000000`(`0` decimal) to `111100111`(`999` decimal).

Claim: we only need 10 testers to find the poisoned bottle. Note: `log2(N) = log2(1000) = 10`.

Algorithm: for the `M`th bottle, we first get the 10-bit binary representation of `M`. If the `i`th bit of the binary number is `1`, we let the `i`th tester to drink the wine from the bottle. Note: `0 < M <1000, 0 < i <10`.

Consider an example where we have the `1st`, `4th`, `9th` tester being dead and other testers being alive after a month. We conclude that the `289th` bottle is the poisoned one since `0100100001` is the binary representation of the decimal number `289`.

Why are `10` testers enough to identify the poisoned one among `1000` bottles?

Because with `10` testers each being dead or alive in the end, we can have a total of `1024` combinations, each of which can be used to uniquely identify one bottle as poisoned from as many as `1024` bottles.

Comment: Since this is schoolwork, you might not want to just give away the answer.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thank you for the tip. I'll be careful with school work type of questions next time.

Answer (score 5):

This is a classic puzzle, so I don't want to immediately give the answer away, but here's a hint: suppose you split up the wine bottles into two groups, each of which contains half the bottles, then have one person test each half.  That would give you a way to narrow down which bottle is poisoned to one half of the bottles.

So the question is this - is there a way to come up with lots of different ways of splitting up the wine bottles into halves and running the above approach in parallel?  As a hint, think about the binary representation of N.

Hope this helps!

Comment: just out of curiosity! doesn't that make it into a binary tree ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest. This basically comes from parallel algorithms.

1. Divide the bottles in n/log2(n). Call each division a subproblem to solve.
2. Assign each of the log2(n) testers to each subproblem in step 1.
3. At the end say one tester dies, say we have log2(n) bottles left and log2(n) - 1 testers.
4. Each tester tests one bottle. And one bottle remains.
5. If no tester dies (or at least show symptoms in first few days... that's my assumption) then we know the culprit is the bottle that was left behind.
6. If any one tester dies(or at least shows sickness) then we know the bottle that was tested by that tester is the culprit.

This we it takes log2(n) + 1 months. Since 1 is a constant we can ignore that and can say it's O(log2(n)).

Answer (score 0):

provide an example:

Label each bottle from 1 to n , and consider each as a binary number. 
e.g. 11 bottles

```
00000001 
00000010 
00000011 
00000100 
00000101 
00000110 
00000111
00001000 
00001001 
00001010 
00001011
```

Now, from the right to left ,  firstly take a drop from each of the bottles whose rightest bit is set  to '1' and deposit in the first cup. 
Secondly take a drop from each bottle whose 2nd bit  is set  '1' and deposit in the second cup.
Continue in similar fashion through the highest bit. So in total we need 4 cups and 4 tasters.

```
taster4 taster3 taster2 tester1
cup4     cup3    cup2     cup1
```

we now map  the tasters to cups and map the cups to bits,  so map tasters to bits 
command tasters to drink.  In a month, some of your tasters will become dead. 
e.g.   taster3 and taster1 become dead 
then set the corresponding bits to 1, and all other bits to 0. The resulting binary number 
`00000101` will identify the poisoned bottle.
the number of tasters f(n)  = (int)(logn)+1  , so f(n) is O(logn)